# How to give variable link to the load function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript. I wanted to ask how can i pass variable link to the .load() function of javascript.

```
var current_link = location.href;

$('#alerts_div').load(current_link '#alerts_div');//to pass div content in page load
```

But this is not working? can anyone help please?

Comment: -1 What? can you explain? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @G Gill I answered but please, at least re-read/debug your code before ask us on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a page fragment, you need to add an additional space:

```
$('#alerts_div').load(current_link + ' #alerts_div');
```

Please read: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Description) to assemble the URL you are trying to read:

```
$('#alerts_div').load(current_link + ' #alerts_div');
```